# msSaveOrOpenBlob work in Edge but not work in Edge WebView

Tags: javascript, webview, microsoft-edge, office-addins

Now Office Add-Ins use new Edge based WebView instead IE 11 based one. My piece of code stop working after this update. I've just try to download file here. This code works correctly if I use it in any browsers. But Office Apps like Excel or Word use WebView version of Microsoft Edge. Debug show me that function window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob is undefined in this case. Please help me fix it.

I try to find any documentation on this matter but without success.

```
        function ClickFunc() {
        var blob = new Blob(['Some Byte Array'], { type: 'application/txt' });
        //output file name
        var fileName = "test.txt";

        //detect whether the browser is IE/Edge or another browser
        //
        //ERROR: In Edge WebView window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob is undefined.  
        //
        if (window.navigator && window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) 
        {
        //To IE or Edge browser, using msSaveorOpenBlob method to download file.
            window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(blob, fileName);
        } else {
            //To another browser, create a tag to downlad file.
            //This part of code for browsers other than IE & Edge.
            const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            const a = document.createElement('a');
            document.body.appendChild(a);
            a.setAttribute('style', 'display: none');
            a.href = url;
            a.download = fileName;
            a.click();

            window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
            a.remove();
        }
    }

   //I use this code in HTML to call function
   <button onclick="ClickFunc()">Click me</button>
```

window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob is undefined when it used in WebView of Microsoft Edge.

Answer (score 3):

Are you using Microsoft Edge WebView2? As mentioned in [the article](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/microsoft-edge/hosting/webview2), the Edge WebView2 is using Microsoft Edge (Chromium) as the rendering engine. `msSaveOrOpenBlob` is exclusive in MS Edge and IE, it will be undefined in Chromium-based Edge.

Comment: Thank you for quick answer. I've just learned text you shared. I'm sure I use WebView1 :-). I have no installed WebView2 SDK or Edge(Chromium), I got this new pain through usual Windows and office 365 update. I suppose, I can't get software in developer preview by this way. 

Also I have part of code, which handle Chrome browser and it work fine. In my case I have access denied error as result.

Comment: I have tested the `msSaveOrOpenBlob` method in WebView1. It is indeed the method has been removed from WebView1. Although WebView uses the same kernel with Edge, there're many functions removed from WebView.

Comment: what is latest on this ?
is there any alternate way to download blob data in edge webview ?

Comment: @YuZhou I am also facing the same issue. Please help with any alternate way.

Comment: Did you guys find any solution to this? I am also facing the same issue.

Comment: @ShubhamNavale Creating a hidden `<a>` in chromium edge and triggering a click on it works just fine.

Comment: I tried updating MS Edge to latest version and it worked without `msSaveOrOpenBlob`. My current version - Version 98.0.1108.56 (Official build) (64-bit)